# Difference in defining function in bash

Tags: bash, function

I have seen function defined two ways in bashrc:

```
dosomething() { ... }
```

and

```
function dosomething() { ... }
```

What difference does it make to use the `function` declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions

> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>
> ```
>  [ function ] name () compound-command [ redirections ]
> ```
>
> This defines a shell function named name. **The reserved word function is
>   optional.** If the function reserved word is supplied, the parentheses
>   are optional.

`function` and omitting parentheses is bash-specific. So to be more portable, don't use it.

Comment: I was using a library that used the function keyword and it messed up my /etc/hosts. This was because the bash shell I was using did not work with the function keyword. This was on ubuntu 13. Watch out for those scripts.